# Resource exhausted while training Xception model on flower_dataset with tensorflow-gpu-2.4.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am having issues while training the TensorFlow model on a flower-dataset of 5 classes. There are 3000+ pictures of flowers in 5 classes. I have installed the necessary library for TensorFlow-gpu. It's
showing resources exhausted.

#### Configuration

- intel i5 1135g7
- Nvidia mx330 2GB
- Tensorflow-gpu==2.4.0
- Cuda11.0.1
- CuDNN8.2

```sh
Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,728,14,14] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

I tried to reduce the BATCH_SIZE too.

Here is my code in tensorflow.

```py
IMAGE_SIZE = (224, 224)
BATCH_SIZE = 32

base_model = keras.applications.Xception(include_top=False,
                                         weights="imagenet",
                                         input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE+ (3, ))

base_model.trainable = True

inputs = layers.Input(shape=IMAGE_SIZE+ (3,),)    
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(x)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_accuract",
                                               patience=5)

epochs = 30
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    shuffle=True,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    callbacks=[early_stopping]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`OOM` basically means that you are getting *out of memory*. Looking at your GPU is only 2 GB, so it is pretty normal to run out of memory in some tasks. You might want to try reducing `BATCH_SIZE` as much as you can (no clue which values you tried so far).
Try setting `BATCH_SIZE` to `8`.

If that does not solve it, you will need to resize all your pictures to avoid consuming that much memory. Try changing the image size to 30x30.